# How can I apply style elements to divs created

Tags: php, css

I have this PHP code that fetches data (an image link and some strings) from my database. The goal is for me to be able to add products (its for an online store) to the database and have that PHP file automatically fetch the data required to display it on the site. I've managed to pull the data I needed but I can't seem to find a way to add some CSS to the divs it creates for each product.

I have already tried linking a CSS file and I don't want to go adding it inline (defeats the purpose of it being automatic)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>testdoc</title>
  <style>
    .prodimg
    {
      border: 20px, red, solid;
    } 
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 
</body>
</html>





<?php
include 'db_connection.php';

$conn = OpenCon();
echo "Connected Successfully";
//query voor var 
$sql = "SELECT prod_id, prod_name, stock, prod_price,images FROM PRODUCTS WHERE prod_name = 'red shirt' OR prod_type = 'tshirt'";
$result = $conn->query($sql); // kijken of er results zijn
$numberofRows=0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    makeDiv($numberofRows,$row);
  } 
} 
else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

function makeDiv($numberofRows,$row)
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $div = $doc->createElement('div');//Create new <div> tag
    $div->setAttribute('class',"prodimg"); // give it a class
    $imglink = $doc->createElement('img'); //create new image
    $doc->appendChild($div);//Add the <div> tag to document
    $imglink->setAttribute('src',$row['images']); //add the source from the database
    $imglink->setAttribute('width',"200px");//give it the right size
    $imglink->setAttribute('margin',"50px"); // setattribute seems to only work once for some reason
    $div->appendChild($imglink); //add the image to the div
    echo $doc->saveHTML(); // save everything 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add style block to the page

```
<style>.prodimg { background: #FF6600 }</style>
```